# How to disable anti-aliasing when scaling up an imageview in android?

Tags: android, imageview, scaling, antialiasing

I have a pixel art that I want to scale up. The problem is when I scale it up, it gets all blurred cause of the antialiasing. Is there a way to disable antialiasing directly from xml?

Comment: have you scaled it with bitmap? and set the scaled image to image view in code?

Comment: I was looking for a more simple way to do it directly in XML. But it doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: scale in code have no complexity!but if you found a way from xml i'm glad to know and if you do it in code, you can set an option to imageview that disable anti alias

Comment: ok, can you tell me how to do it? I tried googling it, but with no success.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i hope its useful

```
Bitmap bmpSource = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), SourceFileId);
//100 is dimension to resizing image size
//Passing filter = false will result in a blocky, pixellated image.
//Passing filter = true will give you smoother edges
Bitmap bmpScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmpSource, 100, 100, false); 


ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(Your imageView Control Id);
img.setImageBitmap(bmpScaled);
```

is this what u want!?

Comment: Thanks, it did help me, but now I have another problem. It seems to work perfectly in mdpi, but when I test it in ldpi and hdpi, it doesnt work as I would like.

Here's a picture: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2wpnlgj&s=5

Comment: @DavidSimka what dimension gives to function?