# Android different device size: ImageButton and bitmap - how to scale right?

Tags: android, button, layout, bitmap, scale

Hi I have made three sets of bitmaps for my application which I use as ImageButtons :

hdpi with 85x85 and 96 resolution,
mdpi with 50x50 with 96 resolution and
ldpi with 35x35 with 96 resolution.

The images are in the hdpi, mdpi and ldpi folders.

The xml is a Linearlayout with 7 Imagebuttons (here one as example):

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fire"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/fire"
        android:onClick="onFireClick" />
```

On my nexus 4 device are the images perfectly scaled in the 4.9''. When I choose a emulator with a really small display there are the small ldpi images loaded -they do not perfect fit but its okay.

But when I try it with a slightly smaller display like a 4.5'' or a 4.3'' the Image Buttons are to big and don't fit in the screen.

Is there a way to scale the ImageButtons that they always fit right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: look at this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19381864/imagebuttons-on-different-sized-devices

Comment: Please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24155422/android-image-button-scale